# How do I get my records from a specific date in time?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.6

Edit: 15:09 2020-07-08, well I solved it, and while it isn't the optimal solution or the most neat and slim one it does what I need it too. So thanks for those who took their time to comment and answer!

So i have a query that i want to input a date into, and then get the records that was "active" during that date. I am currently only using current date so it is very static. But how to make it more dynamic, so that I can as I said chose any date in time, and get that data? What do you suggest?

I'm using postgresql 9.6 in pgadmin 4

don't now if this is of any help but here is my query.....

```
SELECT due.contract_id,due.component,due.due_not_paid, due.current_arrears_days,ob.outstandingamount, due.record_valid_to
FROM
    (SELECT a.record_valid_to, a.contract_id,a.component, sum(a.invoice_non_paid_waivedamount) as due_not_paid,max(no_latedays) as Current_arrears_days
    FROM
        (SELECT 
        sub.contract_id,sub.record_valid_to,sub.invoice_generation_date,sub.invoice_duedate,sub.invoice_paiddate,
        sub.invoice_dueamount,sub.invoice_paid_waivedamount,sub.invoice_non_paid_waivedamount,sub.component,
        CASE WHEN sub.invoice_dueamount = 0 THEN 0 ELSE sub.latedays END as no_latedays,
        CASE WHEN sub.invoice_non_paid_waivedamount > 0 AND invoice_duedate < current_date THEN 'DUE' ELSE 'PAID or non-due' END AS Paid_status
        FROM
            (select contract_id,record_valid_from,record_valid_to,invoice_generation_date,invoice_duedate,invoice_paiddate, invoice_dueamount,invoice_paid_waivedamount,
            CASE WHEN invoice_paid_waivedamount>0  AND (invoice_dueamount=invoice_paid_waivedamount) THEN (invoice_paiddate-invoice_duedate) ELSE (current_date-invoice_duedate) END as latedays,
            (invoice_dueamount-invoice_paid_waivedamount) as invoice_non_paid_waivedamount,component
            from dwd_tb_contracts_invoices where record_valid_to='9999-12-31' 
            ORDER BY invoice_duedate) 
         sub) a
    WHERE a.Paid_status = 'DUE'
    GROUP BY a.record_valid_to, a.contract_id, a.component) due
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (select * from exposure_split('2020-07-06')) ob 
    ON due.contract_id = ob.contract_id
    where due.component = 'INTEREST_INTERMEDIATE'
or due.component = 'PRINCIPAL'
or due.component = 'INTEREST'
or due.component = 'INTEREST_DIFFERENCE'
    order by contract_id
```

Comment: This should be simple enough to answer, but we need a bit more information: What do you consider an "active" record? Do you already have a field you can use for this? Does it contain a date, or a full timestamp? I see you are currently grouping by a.record_valid_to. Is this not giving you what you want?

Comment: Yes pianosaurus you are absolutley correct, I should have written a more clear statement. It's always hard to know how much information and description is enough and sufficient for your readers. Well, I only have a field that contains a date, and this query should give me what I want but due to the fact that the database is structured in well let's say a "funny way" it creates many records valid to, and to go back in time which is what I want to do here, I have to deselect 9999 12 31, and chose a date which is closer to the date  I want. Very time consuming but I solved it!!

Answer (score 1):

If you are speaking of the time of insertion, then you could create a procedure of function that automatically sets the current date and time as a cell of that table and not allow direct access to it and then directly query it. The same can be done, if accessing a row or table is concerned.

I'm not really into SQL neither do I have the rep. to comment, but if can write a code for the same, please let me know...so that I can safely delete the answer then.

Comment: I like your idea, and i tried to sort of do something along your lines, though I don't have permission to create functions in my database due to Im only a summer intern. But what i do have done is that I've worked around the problem, so it actually does that which I intended it to do.

Comment: Glad to know that you liked the idea @KarlPRO

Comment: oh absolutley! I see yoou wanted me to answer you about wether or not you should write a code so that you could delete your answer. How do you want me to do there?

Comment: You could create a sample db and create a table there..For eg, If the table has 3 columns you could add a 4th column to that table or wrap view that has the 4th column. Now you could write a function that sets the creation/last access timestamp as the fourth cells of that record and then maybe not allow a non-admin user to directly access that table/view. I don't know if there is something more better than using functions but this is one of the way to go.